# golang cgo: libevent handler values are set to null during execution

Tags: go, libevent, cgo

i'm working on porting this C API in go https://github.com/shammash/vde3, the library has is own event loop that use libevent, i'm using CGO.

the library require a full vde_event_handler that is composed this way

```
{event_add = 0x7fffe4de0db0, event_del = 0xc2000123a8, timeout_add = 0xc200000090, timeout_del = 0xc200010400}
```

a struct with a series of pointers to functions

during execution this field are set to NULL and i can't understand why, i think it may be the go garbage collector that (for some reason) find the reference dandling and remove them, but this shouldn't be the case

this is the incriminated function https://github.com/kurojishi/govde3/blob/master/govde.go#L23

```
func createNewEventHandler() *C.vde_event_handler {
    var libevent_eh C.vde_event_handler
    C.event_base_new()
    return &libevent_eh
}
```

and here is a gdb log

```
(gdb) p *libevenet_eh
No symbol "libevenet_eh" in current context.
(gdb) p *libevent_eh
$1 = {event_add = 0x7fffe0000900, event_del = 0x30302e3028, timeout_add = 0x65736c6166, timeout_del = 0x0}
(gdb) info locals
libevent_eh = 0xc200000098
err = {__methods = 0x0, __object = 0x0}
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 1, govde.createNewEventHandler ()
at /home/kurojishi/golang/src/github.com/kurojishi/govde3/govde.go:23
23  func createNewEventHandler() C.vde_event_handler {
(gdb) info locals
$ret11 = {event_add = 0x7fffe4de0db0, event_del = 0xc2000123a8, timeout_add = 0xc200000090, timeout_del = 0xc200010400}
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 2, govde.createNewEventHandler ()
at /home/kurojishi/golang/src/github.com/kurojishi/govde3/govde.go:24
24      var libevent_eh C.vde_event_handler
(gdb) info locals
libevent_eh = {event_add = 0x0, event_del = 0x3, timeout_add = 0x7fffe4de0f8f, timeout_del = 0x7fffe4de0f8f}
$ret11 = {event_add = 0x0, event_del = 0x0, timeout_add = 0x0, timeout_del = 0x0}
```

Comment: Is `libevent_eh` populated by the `vde_context_init` call (I don't know libevent at all)? 
Also, doesn't `event_based_new()` have a return value that you need, or at least check?

Comment: this is how the C version use it https://github.com/shammash/vde3/blob/master/src/vde_hub.c#L22 and this is how it's initialized https://github.com/shammash/vde3/blob/master/src/libevent_handler.c#L141 i'm following this pattern, but now i'm thinking i missed something with that extern declaration

Comment: I still don't see how it's supposed to initialize, but regardless, `libevent_eh` in `Init` does not escape that function. That pointer, and the struct it points to are free to be GC'ed at any point thereafter.

Comment: libevent goes in the C.vde_context thanks vde_context_init, you are probabily right about initialization thought

Comment: But that pointer will get GC'ed if there is no reference from Go. You're allocating it in Go inside `createNewEventHandler()`, so the Go  runtime will try to clean it up. As an experiment, stuff it into a global map somewhere and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating a new event handler in Go in createNewEventHandler, passing it to the C code in VdeContext.Init, and then dropping the pointer.  The effect is that sometime after VdeContext.Init returns, the Go garbage collector will collect the event handler structure, even though the C code still has a pointer to it.  The code will be left holding a pointer to memory that will change unpredictably.

When you allocate memory in Go and pass a pointer to C, you must keep the pointer alive in Go for as long as the C code needs to reference it.

Comment: i'm tring to work it out right now in this direction, tomorrow you will hear for me again, thanks meanwhile

Comment: i'm tring things, as this codebase i need some glue code for making it works i'll update when it will be working

Comment: in the end this is the right answer, but on my codebase i've some problem implementing your advice, i'll experiment some more and open a new, more specific issue, many thanks